# Multiple JSON root elements | JSON Encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating an array with several paramaters enclosed in a for loop as per the below:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {

        $jsonarray=array(

        'id' => $x, 
        'title' => $title,
        'url' => $url,

    );

        echo json_encode($jsonarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    }
```

The above code will create 5 arrays and encode them into a JSON as per the below:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "title":"Test Title",
   "url":"http://test.com/"
}{  
   "id":2,
   "title":"Test Title 2",
   "url":"http://test2.com",
}
```

The above JSON output is not a valid JSON as it needs to be objects need to be seperated with an array []. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your array after the loop and add the values in an array, e.g.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {

    $jsonarray[] = array(
                     'id' => $x, 
                     'title' => $title,
                     'url' => $url,
                   );
}

echo json_encode($jsonarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build he complete array before attempting to convert it to a JSON string. Not as you are doing, outputting each occurance individually.

So do it like this

```
$jsonarray = array();

for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    $jsonarray[] = array( 'id' => $x, 
                          'title' => $title,
                          'url' => $url);

}
echo json_encode($jsonarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an array instead

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {

$jsonarray[] = array(
                 'id' => $x, 
                 'title' => $title,
                 'url' => $url,
               );
}

echo json_encode($jsonarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```